# Intercepting HTTP calls to log requests (with request body) and responses in .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-framework-version

I have a .NET Framework 4.6.1 application that I would like to log all incoming requests and all outgoing responses. As the request body is a stream, I have found that it is not that simple, as reading the stream will destroy the body. I have found plenty of tips on how to do this in .NET Core, but as I am using .NET Framework, I am a bit limited. [Here](https://exceptionnotfound.net/using-middleware-to-log-requests-and-responses-in-asp-net-core/) is an example on how to do it in .NET Core, but this is again not available to me. I am using System.Web.Http, Version 5.2.3.0.